# Converting two lists into a dictionary doesn't zip all combinations - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
Cars = {'1': [140.8731392,142.3481116,146.7621232,144.9406286,144.8725356,145.3976902],
        '2': [147.6279494,141.4455089,147.3953295,144.6467237,146.406241,147.0695877],
        '3': [140.7164976,143.4675429,145.9967808,141.7831729,144.4806287,147.7805723],
        '4': [149.359966,147.0236556,146.2931072,148.478762,149.565317,143.9501002],
        '5': [145.9216418,143.3376241,145.2974838,148.80916,143.7103238,145.4369799],
        '6': [146.2192954,149.0914385,146.3690445,143.3845218,140.1431644,149.6484708]
        }
df = DataFrame(Cars,columns= ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])
print (df)
```

If I try to identify which col contain outliers, using:

```
outlier_numbers = []
explantations = []
for col in df.columns:
    quartile_01, quartile_03 = np.percentile(df[col].dropna(), [25, 75])
    iqr = quartile_03 - quartile_01
    lwer_bound = quartile_01 -(1.5 * iqr)
    upper_bound = quartile_03 +(1.5 * iqr)
    outliers_number = ((df[col] < (quartile_01 - 1.5 * iqr)) | (df[col] > (quartile_03 + 1.5 * iqr))).sum() #!=0
    explanation = f"The lower and upper bound of the range for '{col}' respectively is: {lwer_bound} and {upper_bound}"
    if outliers_number >0:
        outlier_numbers.append(outliers_number)
        explantations.append(explanation)
a_dict = {key: value for key, value in zip(outlier_numbers, explantations)}
values_checking = len(outlier_numbers) == 0
```

and then, print outliers_number, I will get [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], meaning that col 2 and 5 contain outliers. But if I check the zipped a_dict, I will get : {1: "The lower and upper bound of the range for '5' respectively is: 141.5670700125 and 148.3405201125"} which doesn't make sense to me. Why only one element, not two elements got zipped?

Comment: Your zipping `[1, 1]` and '[<long string>', '<long string>']` into a dict.  But dict keys are _unique_, so the first `1: <long string>` pair is overwritten by the second, because the key for both is `1`.

Comment: Oh, and is there a way to overcome it? As the value is different.

Comment: It depends on what you want as your keys this would give you keys as 0, 1, etc`a_dict = {i: value for (i, key), value in zip(enumerate(outlier_numbers), explanations)}`.  Or maybe you should append `col` to `outlier_numbers`?

Comment: Good point or I could simply swap explanation and outlier_number. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem is that *outlier_numbers* contains
*[1, 1]* (for both columns *2* and *5* the number of outliers is **1**).

Then, when you create a dictionary:

- The first item has key *1* and the first *explanation*.
- Then the second pair from *zip* has **also** *key == 1*,
  so the (only) existing item is **overwritten** with the
  second *explanation*.

Maybe keys should be column names, not the number of outliers?